# Jmeter: Mobile Internet not working after configuring with system's IP & port as per Recording Controller

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do performance testing of an android app. I have initiated the steps by adding a recording controller, put a port number, used the manual proxy on mobile as per the system's IP but when I try to use the browser, I cannot access the internet. It says no connectivity. I have installed Jmeterrootca certificate as well. Any suggestions folks?

Comment: Are you using a company laptop? maybe you have to set up a proxy in Jmeter so that "Jmeter" can access internet...

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you need the browser if you need to capture the network footprint of the other application?
2. When you set JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as the proxy for the whole operating system you need to ensure that JMeter is capable of reaching the Internet (or at least the backend for the application which traffic you want to simulate). Check if you can open a web page using JMeter's [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) and if is not successful you will need to fix this first.
3. You will need to take some extra steps in order to be able to record secure traffic, check out [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) and [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) articles for more details if needed.